# In javascript replace single quote from string generated using serverside function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my Asp.Net site I have third party library in C# which has Method "LocalizeString" to generate local translation for text for controls.

```
var lblFriendName = '<%=LocalizeString("lblFriendName")%>';
```

This is causing issue for some string. In this case function returns string  : Friend's name
Where single quote is creating issue.

I cant modify server side code. So is there anyway to make this code line working in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This will escape any kinds of special JS characters for you. You should ALWAYS use this method when you want to output a string into JS, you can even have security issues with it! Eg. if the string is `x'; alert('pwn!'); 'y`, you will output this to your browser:

```
var lblFriendName = 'x'; alert('pwn!'); 'y';
```

Comment: you mean something like '<%=HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(LocalizeString("lblFriendName"))%>'; ??

Comment: Worked like charm. and feels me stupid to forget such important function